# How to make outputed html source compact in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Visited http://www.12titans.net/p/s/register.aspx,     right click view source on the page .I found the html source so compact,have no blank. How to do like this in asp.net? 
I am use IE8 ,tks in advance! sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with debugging some spring mvc projects, What i normally do is use chrome, right click on the page and inspect element.  The element explorer is the source code with javascript applied to it, so i might be a little different, but normally for the better

hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate HTML using ASP.NET, just don't insert tabs or line breaks or spaces in the source code, and when you code HTML by hand, do the same thing.

In other words, do it by hand.

You can also use a DOM Parser which should be able to get the bare necessities and print it out without any tabs or whitespace.